# How to run background process in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc web-application . It makes the following:

1.Users submit bulk order.

2.Go to success page immediately.

3.send email and sms to user and admin (separate email for each order)

I wish to run step 3 as background process 
So, how I can do this with spring mvc framework?which is the best technology  for this?Thank You in Advance!

Comment: Read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling, and especially http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy way is to use Spring's [`@Async`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) support.

Example:

```
@Service
public class EmailAndSmsService {

   @Async
   public void emailAndSmsService(YourMessage message) {
       //this code runs in an new thread (when Async is enabled).

       //do suff
   }
}
```

The important point is that **you MUST invoke the `@Async` annotated class from an OHTER bean**. (If you invoke it from the same bean (`this.emailAndSmsService(...)`) then spring can not apply its Async-functionalaty. (You could use real AspectJ compile or loadtime waving to overcome this problem, but this is not the scope of this answer.)

usage

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private EmailAndSmsService emailAndSmsService;

    @RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView yourControllerMethod(...) {
       ...
       emailAndSmsService(message);  
    }

}
```

Config:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
```

@See [Spring Reference chapter 33.4.3 The @Async Annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-async) for more details. Also read the complete [Chapter 33.4 Annotation Support for Scheduling and Asynchronous Execution](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support) to learn how to enable `@Async`-support.

---

An other way to solve the problem would be implementing some queue, where the controller store the messages that should been send, and have a `@Scheduled` annotated method that send the messages that are in this queue.